# HTTPS Only Not Working For Subdomain with Azure App Service

Tags: azure, https, azure-web-app-service

I have configured an Azure web service to use a custom domain and successfully verified both the root domain and subdomain (www) in addition to binding a TLS cert to both.

Custom domain page:
[image]

When I navigate to http://example.com, the browser correctly redirects to https://example.com.

However, when I navigate to the subdomain http://www.example.com, the browser does not redirect to https. I can however navigate directly to my subdomain over https via https://www.example.com.

Why is Azure not enforcing the "Https Only" setting on the subdomain?

Update: screenshot from TLS/SSL settings page:
[image]

Comment: Is there any CORS policy in your application, if any then check and update

Answer (score 0):

It seems everything you have done is okay...
I just post what works on my side, you can have a look and check with yours.

After map custom domain, navigate to TLS/SSL settings, enable Https Only:
[image]

And ensure enable **Https Only** in custom domain page, too:
[image]

Here is my test:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Doris. I have updated the post to include a screenshot of the TLS/SSL settings page as well. It looks like everything is the same in terms of settings. The only difference I can see is that I have verified both the root domain and subdomain (www). Strange that the redirect to HTTPS is not working...

Comment: @user1392897 , I tried add root domain and subdomain together, nothing different.